# Strange behavior inside fork block

Tags: repeat, system-verilog, fork-join

I have a block which looks like this:

```
fork
       begin    
           $display("before repeat");          
           repeat (delay_before_rsp2data) #1ps;
           $display("after repeat");

           $display("some information"); 
           `ovm_do_on_with("do some stuff");   
       end
join_none
```

In almost all cases it works fine, but in one case (that I found), after the `ovm_do_on_with line, it jumps back to the repeat line, and continuing from there. I know this is happening, because what is displayed is:

```
before repeat
after repeat
some information
[all the displays from the `ovm_do_on_with part]
after repeat
some information
[all the displays from the `ovm_do_on_with part]
```

I've tried putting the whole 'repeat' line inside a before end block, switching it with a for loop, and a few more combinations like that, but always the same behavior.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps you should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't see the problem, but you perhaps need to check your semi-colons. There should be one after the first two `$display`s.

Comment: it's not really verifiable, as it only happens on a specific seed on a specific time it enters the block, I don't know if there is any more information I can give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are executing the `fork ... join_none` more than one time (probably in loop) and I guess the `delay_before_rsp2data` is random.
If this is the case, then the `after repeat` you saw may not be from the same thread as the `before repeat`.

My suggestion, add some kind of `id` to debug and track which thread it is from. For example

```
int id=0;

task my_fork;
  fork
    automatic int k; // !! must be automatic
    begin
      id++; k = id;
      $display("before repeat, id %d", k);
      repeat(delay) #1ps;
      $display("after repeat, id %d", k);
      `uvm_do_on_with();
    end
  join_none
endtask
```

Then you should be able to track the threads and correlate them.
Remember to use `automatic` variable inside `fork join_none` so that it's thread has unique `id`.

Some quick example:

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4vRd

Comment: Yeah, that was it (incidentally after being stuck on this for two days, I figured it out about 10 minutes before you replied). Thanks! 

It was all inside a forever loop whose first line is a 'get', so the fork kept being interrupted by a new packet. The solution was to simply move the delay into the sequence called by 'ovm_do', leaving no where for the new packets to interrupt the flow and overwrite the variables (which were not local enough)